# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while passing data from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am passing values from a gridview to next page. The gridview is connected to a database.The gridview shows the data as I want but when I try to pass the row data of gridview to next page it throws an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

The gridview is as follows:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
      RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
   runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000000"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderText="TaskId" ItemStyle-Width="30" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TaskId" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-Width="150" SortExpression="Title" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Reward" HeaderText="Reward" SortExpression="Reward" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAllotted" HeaderText="TimeAllotted" SortExpression="TimeAllotted" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PosterName" HeaderText="PosterName" SortExpression="PosterName" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDetails" runat="server" Text="Send Details" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/test/Tasks.aspx?RowIndex=" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3AC0F2" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

 <RowStyle BackColor="#A1DCF2"></RowStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ABCD %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Task]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code for 'Tasks.aspx.cs' is as below:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        lblTaskId.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
        lblTitle.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        lblBody.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        lblReward.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
        lblTimeAllotted.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
        lblPosterName.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;


    }
}
```

I get an error message on the line below:

```
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
```

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that `FindControl` method isn't actually finding the control, making your `GridView1` variable null. Ensure the control is well inside the page and that the name is right.

**EDIT:**

If you are using master pages, there's indeed some issues with `FindControl`. Rick Strahls explains it in [his blog](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl):

```
*The problem is that when you use MasterPages the page hierarchy drastically changes.
Where a simple this.FindControl() used to give you a control instance you now have to
drill into the container hierarchy pretty deeply just to get to the content container.*
```

He also has an example on how to make it work. Basically, you must find your content control from the master page (using `page.Master.FindControl`). Then from *that* point you should be able to reach to your grid control.

In your scenario, since you want a control from the previous page:

```
var GridView1 = page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("ContentContainer").FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
```

Comment: what can i do about it?

Comment: so i shouldnt use the previouspage command? but when i use the above code it says 'page' is not present in the current context

Comment: @Mash sorry, I forgot to put in `PreviousPage` access. See my edited answer again. Of course remember that your container name might differ.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your gridview does not have any bound data when "this.Page.PreviousPage != null" is true. That is, unless you bind your data in some other initialization handler.

Because there is no data, there are no Rows which means that GridView1.Rows[rowIndex] would be null.

Comment: I understand that.One interesting thing is when i use the same setup without any masterpage,it works.Whats with that?

Comment: The problem isn't related to the data. If it was then the line wouldn't throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Ah, your original question did not mention that you were using a Master page. That does make sense. Glad it worked out for you. :)